# Structuring page counter MYSQLI database

Tags: php, database, database-design, mysqli

I'm going to be building a page counter for a site to determine views of different pages. Basically, I have users that I'd like to track with respect to page views of about 120 specific pages.

I'm having trouble determining the most efficient way to do this as well as the logic behind it. I was trying 3 tables, but this would end up in many unnecessary rows. I thought storing an array in a single field then updating the array, but I'm not sure this will grow or if it is even possible. Below is my way of limiting the number of requests. Basically every 100 will count 100. Any ideas for structuring this?

```
$sample_rate = 100;
if(mt_rand(1,$sample_rate) == 1) {
//update set query
}
```

Comment: What details do you need to keep in the database?

Comment: The page id associated with the page views. The page id will come from a standard table with info.

Comment: Do you need just the number of views, do you need user ip, do you need browser type? There are so many things you can keep for statistics, so it's impossible to answer before getting these details...

Comment: I'll be using an existing user table and my first thought was to use that in the update command. I would just need page id and page view count for each user. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation in the comments I would recommend the following simple design:

```
TblPages
--------
Page_Id (pk)
Page_URL (unique)

TblViews
--------
View_Page_Id
View_User_Id
View_Count 
(pk is View_Page_Id + View_User_Id)
```

Whenever a user views a page, you execute a stored procedure that will either insert a record to the TblViews table if there is no record for that user and page, or update the View_Count of the existing record.

To get all the views for a page you use SUM(View_Count) and group by View_Page_Id, to get all the page views by a user you group by View_User_Id, etc.